# Undo or Edit Windows in Intellij Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I accidentally clicked a key from my laptop that I do not remember and my Android Studio menu window changed.

[image]

I want to have it to be the default window view which is

[image]

I searched for a way to undo it or reverse it but could not find anything. 
If this is a duplicate, please point me to the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second image posted in your question shows the toolbar and the navigation bar, in order to make these visible use the following menu items:

- `View > Toolbar`
- `View > Navigation Bar`